# List of USB Ethernet Controllers supported by iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, usb, ethernet

Is there any official or unofficial list of USB ethernet adapters supported by iPad Pro (2021) (or other Apple devices)?

I tried using adapter with Asix AX88772B controller, but it looks that iPad has no driver for this controller.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a list, Belkin sells an USB-C to Ethernet [on the Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such list. iPad OS does not need a driver for each and every individual USB ethernet adapter out there - instead it supports (some of the) standards for networking over USB.

I have used a number of different USB-ethernet adapters with success with the iPad - including adapters from Apple, Belkin, DeLock and Digitus.